# Looking to read cookie array in Console

Tags: javascript, cookies

Written this piece of Code to pass array into Cookie

```html
<script>
var products = [];
 {
  var products = [{
'name': '$1 Silver Membership Trial - Silver-Membership-3-Month',        
'price': '279.88',
'quantity': 1
  }]
}
  
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
 if (days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
 }
 else var expires = "";
 document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
  createCookie('products', JSON.stringify(products));
  createCookie('revenue', 279.88);
</script>
```

When trying to this piece Code in Console does not get array value

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(createCookie.get('products')));
```

[image: Here are my local cookies pictured]

Answer (score 0):

To get all cookies for the current domain you can use `document.cookie`.

If you want to get a specific cookie, you must work with that `string` and extract it.

You can use this `function` to get a cookie buy it's name:

```
function getCookieByName(cookiename) {
  const cookieString = RegExp(cookiename + "=[^;]+").exec(document.cookie);
  return decodeURIComponent(!!cookieString ? cookieString.toString().replace(/^[^=]+./, '') : '');
}
```

and then just call it like this:

```
console.log(getCookieByName('products'));
```